# Capacitive proximity sensing - pcb pad

Tags: pcb, proximity-sensor

Does capacitance of pcb's copper used in conjunction with capacitance proximity sensor (analog) rises or lowers when the obstacle get closer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the area is the same capacitance decreases as distance increases. If we have two objects that form a capacitor decreasing distance means increasing capacitance.

[image]
Source: https://passive-components.eu/capacitors-capacitance-dipoles-and-dielectric-absorption/